# how to set the ng-model to a property of an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

from this example
http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/

How can I set   `$scope.correctlySelected`  directly to the value on selecting in the select box and not to the entire object for e.g.
    `{ label: 'one', value: 1 }`,

So on selecting anything `$scope.correctlySelected` should be `1` or `2`
and not the entire object

`{ label: 'one', value: 1 }`

or

```
{ label: 'two', value: 2 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AXHeA/

This is how you do it:

```
<select ng-model="selected"
        ng-options="opt.value as opt.label for opt in options">
```

And then you can assign it like so:

```
$scope.selected = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to just set `$scope.correctlySelected = 2;`, right? If so then you just need to do this for the ng-options directive:

```
<select ng-model="correctlySelected" ng-options="opt.value as opt.label for opt in options">
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/89/